# Passing return data to another function in same controller laravel

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Try to connect to external API. 
In first function, I already received token with authentication. 
To send POST request, I need to put xtoken that I received from first function as second function. 
I don't know how to send value to second function (registerUser)

```
Route::get('/connect', 'Guzzlecontroller@registerUser')->name('registeruser');
```

this is my route file

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;

class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    public function Gettoken()
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $request = $client->get(
            'http://api01.oriental-game.com:8085/token',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'X-Operator' => 'mog189b',
                    'X-key' => 'sQxAVNaEMe0TCHhU',

                ]
            ]

        );
        $response = $request->getBody();
        $tokenReturn = json_decode($response, true);
        $xtoken = array("x-token:" . $tokenReturn['data']['token'],);

        $this->registerUser($xtoken);
    }

    public function registerUser($xtoken)
    {

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url = "http://api01.oriental-game.com:8085/register";

        $request = $client->post($url,  [
            'headers' => $xtoken,
            'body' => [
                'username' => 'test1',
                'country' => 'Korea',
                'fullname' => 'test user1',
                'language' => 'kr',
                'email' => 'testuser1@test.com',

            ]
        ]);
        $response = $request->send();

        dd($response);
    }
}
```

Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\GuzzleController::registerUser(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

this is error I am getting. 
please help me to how to send $xtoken value to registerUser function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Laravel is calling registerUser directly instead of going through getToken. So the token is never retrieved and passed to the register action.

Instead of calling `registerUser()` from `Gettoken()`. Have `Gettoken()` return the token and call it from `registerUser()`

```
public function Gettoken()
{
    ...

    return $xtoken;
}

public function registerUser()
{
    $xtoken = $this->Gettoken();

    ...
}
```